# Lax limits and colimits in the category of relations

Tags: ct.category-theory

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262911/comma-objects-in-the-bicategory-of-profunctors) discussion pointed out that the bicategory $\bf Prof({\cal V})$ admits all lax co/limits.

Before embarking into the task to give a characterization in general, I would like to understand the situation by negative thinking; what does the general definition becomes in the case of ${\cal V}=\{0,1\}$. There, a ${\cal V}$-profunctor is a relation between two sets, so the universal property of $\text{lax.lim } \cal F$ can be read as a property of the bicategory $\bf Rel$.

Of course, also examples where you only consider discrete categories (so that ${\bf Prof}({\cal V})(A,B)\cong {\bf Set}^{A\times B}$) are welcome.

Comment: If $\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$, then a $\mathcal{V}$-category is not just a set but a poset (or more precisely a preorder).  This level of generality is necessary for lax colimits to exist: the lax colimit of a lax diagram in the bicategory $\mathbf{Rel}$ of *sets* and relations will generally no longer be a set but a more general preorder.

Comment: By the way, I misspoke in the other discussion: Prof doesn't have lax limits of all functors, only of lax functors.